# Filter array and add a property

Tags: javascript

I have an array where I have the weekly progress of some projects .

In the cuurent week, timestamp of 1529539200 or date 06/21/2018, I have the information of 3 projects. Project 20, 21 and 22.

In the other week, a week before the current 06/14/2018, there's only information of 2 projects. Because project 22 didn't exist.

```
progressList = [
  // current 06/21/2018
  {
    project: 20, 
    timestamp: 1529539200, // seconds
    current: true,
    progress: 90
  },
  {
    project: 21, 
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    current: true,
    progress: 70
  },
  {
    project: 22,
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    current: true,
    progress: 100
  },
  // 06/14/2018
  {
    project: 20, 
    timestamp: 1528934400, // a week before (1529539200 - 604800)
    current: false,
    progress: 80
  },
  {
    project: 21, 
    timestamp: 1528934400,
    current: false,
    progress: 50
  }  
]
```

What I need is a list of current projects, but includes a new property "increase", that is equals to the difference between current project progress and the progress of the week before.

For example I should get something like this:

```
currentProgressList = [
  {
    project: 20, 
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    current: true,
    progress: 90,
    increase: 10 // difference
  },
  {
    project: 21, 
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    current: true,
    progress: 70,
    increase: 20
  },
  {
    project: 22,
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    current: true,
    progress: 100,
    increase: 0 // 
  }
]
```

I guess that filtering the projects by `current` property may be simple:

```
listadoprogresss.filter(p => {
  return p.current === true
})
```

But, I don't know how to add the `increase` property according with my needs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can simply use the Array map method to generate a new Array with the 'increase' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, you can adjust the *checkIncrease* to suit your solution. but run the code snippet

```js
let checkIncrease = function(list, p) {
    let prevProgress = list.find(np => np.project === p.project && !np.current)
    var increase = 0;
    // confirm that its defined
    if (prevProgress) increase = p.progress - prevProgress.progress
    
    // create a clone and return
    return  { project: p.project, timestamp: p.timestamp, current: p.current, progress: p.progress, increase: increase }
}

let getProgressIncrease = function(progressList) {
  return  progressList
  .filter(p => p.current)
  .map(p => checkIncrease(progressList, p))
}


var progressList = [
  // current 06/21/2018
  {
    project: 20, 
    timestamp: 1529539200, // seconds
    current: true,
    progress: 90
  },
  {
    project: 21, 
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    current: true,
    progress: 70
  },
  {
    project: 22,
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    current: true,
    progress: 100
  },
  // 06/14/2018
  {
    project: 20, 
    timestamp: 1528934400, // a week before (1529539200 - 604800)
    current: false,
    progress: 80
  },
  {
    project: 21, 
    timestamp: 1528934400,
    current: false,
    progress: 50
  }  
]

// try it out
let result = getProgressIncrease(progressList)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const progressList = [
  { project: 20, timestamp: 1529539200, current: true, progress: 90 },
  { project: 21, timestamp: 1529539200, current: true, progress: 70 },
  { project: 22, timestamp: 1529539200, current: true, progress: 100 },
  { project: 20, timestamp: 1528934400, current: false, progress: 80 },
  { project: 21, timestamp: 1528934400, current: false, progress: 50 }  
]

function getCurrentProgressList(progressList) {

  const projects = [];
  const indexes = {};
  
  for(const Project of progressList) {
    const index = indexes[Project.project];
    const CurrentProject = projects[index];

    if (Project.current) {
      indexes[Project.project] = projects.length;
      projects.push({ ...Project, increase: 0 });
    } else if (index !== undefined) {
      const a = CurrentProject.progress;
      const b = Project.progress;
      CurrentProject['increase'] = a - b;
    }
  }
  
  return projects;
}

console.log(getCurrentProgressList(progressList));
```